# Tab Bar controller disappearing when moving to another view (iOS SDK, Using storyboards)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uitabbar

I am building an iPhone app using storyboards and I have a problem with the tab bar controller. On one of the views that is linked from the tab bar controller (view1), there is a button that leads to another view (view2). On View2, there is a button that leads back to View1. Very straight forward. But when I go from view1 to view2, the tab bar disappears, and even worse, when I go back to View1, the tab bar is still gone... 
How can I fix that? (I have yet to put ANY code in the app, there is only the storyboard and the apple provided AppDelegate Class (and also a main file I suppose, but I am not intending on touching that).

Any Reply is Highly appreciated!

Comment: How are you presenting the second view?

Comment: when The user clicks the button it just transfers them to View2

Comment: Did you do any setup for this? Or did you just use the tab bar functions. From your problem it sounds like you're using a segue

Comment: Yes I am indeed using A Segue. As I have mentioned before, I am using storyboards And I have yet to write on line of code. (I guess a couple of lines is what needed to solve this problem... ;)

Comment: Not necessarily. Did you just drag a tab bar controller onto the storyboard and just leave everything the way it was?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you do a modal segue from a view that is a tab bar view, it will get rid of the tab bar for the modal view you are presenting.

Secondly, when you segue you are creating a new instance of the view controller.  So I am guessing you are segueing from view1 to view2 and losing the tab bar, then you are segueing back to view1.  At this point you have created view1, view2, and a second copy of view1 that does not have a tab bar.

I would suggest one of two things.

1.) If you want to keep the tabs at the bottom when you segue from view1 to view2, then click on view1, at the top of the screen select Editor/Embed In/ Navigation Controller.  This will embed your view1 in a navigation controller.  Then if you change your segue from Modal to Push it will keep your tab bars at the bottom.  The navigation bar at the top also make it easy to go back from view 2 to view 1 the correct way (by popping the view) rather than creating a new segue.  If you do not like the navigation bar, then you can change the "Top Bar" property to "None" in the inspector.  You will then need to create some other way in view2 to get back to view1.  (BY POPPING THE CONTROLLER, NOT BY SEGUEING)

2) If you don't want to set up a navigation controller you will have a little bit harder time keeping the tab bar stuff at the bottom of the view2 controller.  In fact, I'm not sure you can do it at all with a modal segue, you'd probably have to write some type of custom segue.  Either way, If you want to transition back to view1 and get to the correct controller (not a new version without the tabs) then you need to attach an action to whatever button you are using to segue and use the following code (I also attached the code for navigation controller push segues, in case you create a navigation controller and get rid of the navigation bar.)

For Modal Segue:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

For Push segue:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Your best bet is to use the navigation controller method, as you are assured to keep your tabs.  You can then either use the navigation bar to return (the easy way, no code needed) or you can get rid of it and use a button and the code above.

Good luck!

Comment: I used solution 1.  But when I did (selected view #1), I had two navigation controllers because I already had one in my storyboard.  I removed the parent nav controller that was behind my tab bar controller.  Instead I used a nav controller like this.   tab bar controller -> nav bar controller -> <domain> table controller -> <domain> detail table controller.

So for each tab I have it's own independent nav controller.  There may be a shared way of using one nav controller but it seems to be working quite well.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how I have done it on a few projects.  It is what I was trying to portray above.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, i know this is an old question but `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` is deprecated in iOS 6.

What i used is:

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`